# How do I prove that $\ln n > 1$ when $n > 2$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I've tried looking at the Taylor series of the function $\ln x$, which is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} (x-1)^n,$$ but wasn't able to extract any useful information out. I haven't tried induction but even if it's possible to prove this via induction, I'd rather see a constructive proof, if it's not too much to ask. Thanks for your help.

Edit: Here $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Is $n$ a natural number?  Otherwise, notice that $\ln(2.0001)\approx 0.6932<1$.  If it is a natural number, then you should probably note that $n>2$ can be rewritten as $n\geq 3$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yes, $n$ is an integer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Anyway, this series converges only for $0<x<2$.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks so much. Hadn't thought of that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It amounts to showing that for $n>2$, $n>\mathrm e$. Now $\mathrm e$ is the limit of the *increasing* sequence $\;a_n=\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^n$, and $a_1=2\mkern1.5mu$…

Comment: That's so obvious. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for the logarithm to base $b$, $\log_b b = 1$.

The logarithm (to any base) is a strictly monotonous function and so $\log_b a>1$ if $a>b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac1x>0$ for $x>2$, so the function is monotonically increasing. It suffices to show the conclusion for $n=3$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get why this suffices. Isn't the last inequality also true for numbers $0 < x \le 2$ also? How does this prove the inequality in question exactly?

Comment: The fact that the function is monotonically increasing means that $f(n)>f(3)$ for every $n>3$. You can cocnvince yourself by looking at its graph. I'm not sure which inequality you think is true for numbers $0<x\leq 2$ also, if you're referring to $1/x>0$, yes, but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use the fact that $e < 3$ you can reason as follows:

- $\ln x$ is the inverse function of the strictly increasing function $e^x$. So, it is also strictly increasing.
- $\ln 3 > 1 \Leftrightarrow 3 > e$, which is true.
- Per induction you have $\ln (n+1) = \ln (n(1+\frac{1}{n})) = \ln n + \underbrace{\ln ((1+\frac{1}{n}))}_{>0}$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it using the OP's Taylor expansion (and the fact that $\ln x$ is an increasing function of $x$):

If $n\ge3$. then

$$\ln n\ge\ln3\gt\ln2.89=2\ln1.7=2\left(0.7-{(0.7)^2\over2}+{(0.7)^3\over3}-{(0.7)^4\over4}+\cdots \right)\gt2\left(0.7-{(0.7)^2\over2}+{(0.7)^3\over3}-{(0.7)^4\over4}\right)$$

It remains to calculate

$$=0.7-{(0.7)^2\over2}+{(0.7)^3\over3}-{(0.7)^4\over4}\approx0.5093\gt{1\over2}$$

Remark: If you're willing to check that $3\gt(1+1/\sqrt2)^2$, then you can avoid the final messy calculation, using instead that

$$\ln3\gt2\left({1\over\sqrt2}-{1\over4}+{1\over6\sqrt2}-{1\over16} \right)={28\sqrt2-15\over24}\gt{28\cdot1.4-15\over24}={39.2-15\over24}\gt1$$

**Added later**: Even easier is

$$\ln3\gt\ln2.89=2\ln1.7\gt2\ln1.69=4\ln1.3\gt4\left(0.3-{(0.3)^2\over2} \right)=4(0.3-0.045)\gt4(0.3-0.05)=1$$

Comment: I'd hoped that Taylor's series would help and it does. Thanks.